# How can I use json validator without installing any external software in python?

Tags: python, json, schema, json-schema-validator

I have used many methods instead of installing JSON schema.validation is required for me because I have one schema file and JSON file. Both files need to validate and the JSON file should satisfy all the properties of the schema file. if it is satisfied with all the properties it just displays output with "schema is valid".

Answer (score 1):

When you say "no external software", does that include Python modules?

Python module jsonschema (https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) looks like it might do what you're after.